# How to debug web connection in firefox on TCP level?

Tags: debugging, http, firefox, tcp, firefox-addon

I have a spooky case - my unlimited stream from server we created (live generated, FLV file with undeclared length) which shall be played via flash player application I created (which is as simple as can be) plays several seconds (mostly one or 2) and stops in firefox. ONLY in firefox for windows. In IE (5-9), any chrom, any safary, firefox under Linux all plays as it should. But on any FF we tried (2-4) it just somehow kills the stream. I stream to flash player via tcp which emulates http. so for example fiddler 2 does not capture it, wireshark does but it is quite hard to filter only firefox requests.

So I search for some connection monitor inside FF... like a plugin or something more native to ff. Is there something?

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to filter for the protocol in wireshark? ( and of course no other streaming thing should run)

Answer (score 2):

You could try [logging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_Logging) things from the Firefox end. You can choose to log at the HTTP level or at the socket level, for instance.

Comment: I dont think flash TCP connections show up through firefox like this, although I might be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the [Apache TCP Monitor](http://ws.apache.org/commons/tcpmon/).  Would allow you to trap only your FF requests easily.